# Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN". D3 JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

I am trying D3 to develop new barchart. This is my first try to d3

I followed one article [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193527/d3-barchart-with-ajax-data) and based on it I am trying to develop one barchart by writing below code.

My code look like

```
function get_data() {
    console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
    return $.ajax({
        url : "/group/guest/query/", // the endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method
    });
};


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10, "");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var ajdata = get_data();
var k = [];
ajdata.success(function (data) {

  var obj  = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

obj.forEach(function(d) {
  d.created_date = d.created_date;
  d.jobs_fail = +d.jobs_fail;
  k.push(d.created_date)
});


x.domain(obj.map(function(d) {
  return d.date_created;
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(obj, function(d) {

  //alert(JSON.stringify(d.jobs_fail));
  return d.jobs_fail;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Count");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date_created);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.jobs_fail);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.jobs_fail);
  });


function type(d) {
  d.jobs_fail = +d.jobs_fail;
  return d;
}
});
```

I am pulling the data form one ajax request and the ajax response looks like below.

```
[ { "date": "2017-12-28", "jobs_fail": 2, "jobs_resub": 7, "jobs_success": 18 }, { "date": "2017-12-27", "jobs_fail": 20, "jobs_resub": 31, "jobs_success": 50 }, { "date": "2017-12-26", "jobs_fail": 22, "jobs_resub": 27, "jobs_success": 49 }, { "date": "2017-12-25", "jobs_fail": 11, "jobs_resub": 8, "jobs_success": 18 }, { "date": "2017-12-24", "jobs_fail": 5, "jobs_resub": 2, "jobs_success": 4 }, { "date": "2017-12-23", "jobs_fail": 10, "jobs_resub": 16, "jobs_success": 23 }, { "date": "2017-12-22", "jobs_fail": 51, "jobs_resub": 54, "jobs_success": 97 } ]
```

When I ran this code I am getting the error.But my x axis dates (created_date) filed data is appearing on chart x axis.

```
Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I understand this is something on y axis but I am not able to find any solution for it please guide me what might I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please include the `function y(...)` that is being called here: `.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.jobs_fail); })`

Comment: @PeterB please elaborate more I could not get

Comment: My comment should be clear. However I just noticed that you have variables `x` and `y`, and also you seem to be calling functions named `x(...)` and `y(...)`. That it likely to cause issues, which you may already be experiencing. To fix this you need to rename either the variables or the functions. E.g rename the functions to `getX(...)` and `getY(...)`.

Comment: @PeterB changed the variable still getting the same issue

Comment: You still need to supply the `function y(...)`. Until then, expect no further help.

Comment: @PeterB `y` is just the scale, which OP supplied in the question. That's not a problem, OP is using it correctly.

Comment: @burning check your AJAX and the parsing. It's working with hardcoded data (however, there is no `date_created`, just `date`): https://jsfiddle.net/4tL7anje/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi All after spending lots of time and help from comment I am able to fix this issue.

So problem is in below piece of code.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date_created);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.jobs_fail);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.jobs_fail);
  });
```

I am storing the parsed `data` into a variable called `obj` whereas I am using the `data` under `.data` since data has no value so it is not able to attach the values just replace data with obj and it works for me.

Thanks all for your support